# How to set an exact pitch in Minecraft Java 1.16.1 Resource Pack

Tags: assets, audio, minecraft-modding, sound, music

I'm trying to make a resource pack in Minecraft Java 1.16.1. The pack will replace all of the Minecraft sounds with LoZ BotW sounds. The first thing I did was put the BotW pickup sound in place of the pop. I got it to play, and it workd, but...

The only problem is that the pitch alters a bit every time I pick up something. I found what I thought was an answer on the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sounds.json), the `pitch: 1` tag.

So I did this:

```json
"entity.item.pickup": {
    "sounds": [
      {
        "name": "random/pop",
        "pitch": 1,
      }
    ],
    "subtitle": "subtitles.entity.item.pickup"
  }
```

I went back into the game and it did not work. It still changed everytime I picked something up. I'm not completely sure that the `pitch` tag keeps it at that pitch, or it it just puts the base pitch at that, but still changes.

Can you help? You can see the pack [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aNDXMkvhuBT1pDU4HNM4wBuAl4t_2qcL/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you seen [this bug report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-36042)?

Comment: I saw, what can I do about it?

Comment: Vote on the bug report for it to get fixed?

Comment: Ugg... Ok. Isn't that bug from before 1.10.x?

Comment: Yes, but it is still open. You can see the affected game versions on the bug tracker.